# run sql script on remote database(oracle) from local machine

Tags: unix

i am trying to run a sql script on remote database from local machine...smoething like this--

the unix script contains--

sqlplus / @db

i want to add something to this command so that is is able to run a sql script on the database "db"

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlplus [login]/[password]@[database] @[scriptfile location]
```